# Angular 4 Renderer2 with dynamic element id

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a dynamic `id` as shown below.Can you tell me how to get this `id` from the component (`ts`) file?

**Note:** My requirement here is, I need to scroll the content to that dynamic item when the user clicks a button (actually here is an item of Bar chart.I can handle that.)

**.html**

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let interval of intervals; let i = index" id="{{interval.key}}">
    <ion-card-header>
      {{interval.sleepingTimeRange}} {{interval.timeDuration}}
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      {{interval.notes}}
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

I have tried as shown below.But I know this is a very BAD way of doing that.How can I do this using `Angular 4 Renderer2`?

**.ts**

```
 scrollTo(elementId: string) {
        let yOffset = document.getElementById(elementId).offsetTop;//This is BAD
        this.content.scrollTo(0, yOffset, 4000)
    }
```

This is the method where `scrollTo()` is being called.

```
subscribeIntervals(): void {
        this.events.subscribe('intervals', (data, selectedItem) => {
            this.intervals = [];

            _.forEach(data, (value, key) => {
                let interval: any = {
                    notes: '',
                 };

                interval.key = value.key;
                this.intervals.push(interval);
            });

            this.scrollTo(selectedItem.key);//scroll to

        });
    }
```

**Error: When implemented the @Günter Zöchbauer solution**

> polyfills.js:3 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse
>   errors: Can't bind to 'scrollIntoView' since it isn't a known property
>   of 'ion-card'.
>   1. If 'ion-card' is an Angular component and it has 'scrollIntoView' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'ion-card' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
>
> ][scrollIntoView]="interval.key">
>
> ```
> <ion-card-header> "): ng:///AppModule/SummaryPage.html@96:62 Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'scrollIntoView' since it
> ```
>
> isn't a known property of 'ion-card'.
>   1. If 'ion-card' is an Angular component and it has 'scrollIntoView' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'ion-card' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
>
> ][scrollIntoView]="interval.key">
>
> ```
> <ion-card-header> "): ng:///AppModule/SummaryPage.html@96:62
> at g (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7133)
> at syntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:113362:34)
> at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:123371:19)
> at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:137054:39)
> at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:136978:62
> at Set.forEach (native)
> at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:136978:19)
> at createResult (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:136863:19)
> at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14529)
> at n.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9741)
> at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:6774
> at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15213)
> at n.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10390)
> at a (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:5313)
> at g (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7133)
> at syntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:113362:34)
> at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:123371:19)
> at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:137054:39)
> at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:136978:62
> at Set.forEach (native)
> at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:136978:19)
> at createResult (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:136863:19)
> at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14529)
> at n.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9741)
> at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:6774
> at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15213)
> at n.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10390)
> at a (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:5313)
> at g (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7133)
> at l (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:6251)
> at l (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:5937)
> at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:6765
> at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15213)
> at n.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10390)
> at a (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:5313)
> ```

**Error 2 :**

> core.es5.js:1085 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTo' of
>   undefined
>       at SummaryPage.scrollTo (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:71046:88)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:71015:19
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:95387:36
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Events.publish (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:95386:11)
>       at SVGRectElement. (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:138265:34)
>       at SVGRectElement. (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:55277:16)
>       at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15213)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:4415:37)
>       at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15134)
>       at n.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10390)
>       at SVGRectElement.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:16170)

Comment: Where is the button? You usually don't read from the DOM in Angular, this is why the renderer doesn't offer anything about reading from the DOM.

Comment: Actually, a button here is an item of Bar chart (SVG).You can think when the user clicks it then it has been called `scrollTo()` method.@GünterZöchbauer

Comment: I still don't know how the button is related to the HTML above. I can't see anything related to SVG in your question. Therefore I don't know what information could be available to the button.

Comment: I don't think there is another way of reading `offsetTop`. There are only other ways to get the element reference.

Comment: Please see the update on my post @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Still not sure what the question actually is about. If you have to read from the DOM, then you have to do it, no matter if it's considered bad or not.

Comment: Let me explain this.I need a requirement like this on StackOverflow commenting highlight system.When you click this URL, it directly goes to your comment and highlights it.Me too need that kind of requirement. Do you know how to do that?Any suggestion, please?  @GünterZöchbauer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568938/angular-4-renderer2-with-dynamic-element-id?noredirect=1#comment74189263_43568938

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want without reading from the DOM:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[scrollIntoView]'
})
class ScrollIntoViewDirective {
  @Input() key:string;

  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

  srcrollTo() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let interval of intervals; let i = index" 
   [scrollIntoView]="interval.key">
```

```
@ViewChildren(ScrollIntoViewDirective) scrollIntoView:QueryList<ScrollIntoViewDirective>;

scrollTo(elementId: number) {
  this.scrollIntoView.toArray().find((s) => s.key == elementId).scrollTo();
}
```

Comment: OK sure.I'll implement this and will let you know.Thanks.

Comment: Hope I need to give this no? `id="{{interval.key}}"`  on `ion-card`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. I don't see a need for it.

Comment: Then which value should I pass as `elementId`? Because I have a list of items.I have decided to segregate those using this unique key `id="{{interval.key}}"`.You can see that on my post. Without that how this works? Can you please explain it?

Comment: Actually I don't know. I still have no idea what your question is about.

Comment: I have a list of unique items.Inside the `subscribeIntervals()` method (you can see that on my question) where I need to dynamically scroll it to particular item. Here I can pass that unique key `this.scrollTo(selectedItem.key);//scroll to`.Hope it is clear now for you.

Comment: You can add an `@Input() key:string` to the directive and use it like `[scrollIntoView]="interval.key"` and then query `this.scrollIntoView.toArray().find((s) => s.key == elementId).scrollTo();`

Comment: Can you please update that on your original post? Thanks.

Comment: I have implemented your solution.But it gives a huge error.Can you please see that on my question?

Comment: You need to add `ScrollIntoViewDirective` to `declarations: [...]` in your `@NgModule(...)`

Comment: Sorry, no idea.

Comment: Problem is on this `[scrollIntoView]="interval.key"`.When I remove it no issues.Can't we assign a value like that? Any idea?

Comment: When I do like this `scrollIntoView="interval.key"` no issues there.But this says `undefined` `this.scrollIntoView.toArray().find((s) => s.key == elementId)`.Any idea?

Comment: If you can create a Plunker that allows to reproduce, I'll have a look.